# There are N friends and each of them have A[i] amount of money. Check whether equal money can be distributed among all of them. Give C code

Tags: c

So this is the code i came up with but why is this not getting accepted as a valid solution on codechef. Constraints have been taken care of and both i/o formats are correct. THIS IS JUST A SIMPLE PRACTICE QUESTION NOT A CONTEST QUESTION.
Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T > 0 && T < 10)
    {
        int N;
        int sum = 0;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
        {
            int A;
            scanf("%d", &A);
            sum += A;
        }
        if (sum%N == 0 )
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
        T--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem? There's no way we can tell whether the code does what it's supposed to without knowing *precisely* what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: The definition of a bug is that a program deviates from its specification. In order to know whether there is a bug or what it is, we need to know (a) the program, and (b) the specification. You have not given the full specification. So we cannot know what the bug is.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/ECJN202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem specification says “1 ≤ *T* ≤ 10”. When the input *T* is 10, the program in this question prints no output, because the code `while (T > 0 && T < 10)` never executes the body of the loop, since `T < 10` is false.

Comment: Holy cow man. It got accepted just because i changed <10 to <=10. It was such a silly mistake. This simple mistake is so embarrasing.